# Sliding door drapes rod - special rod kit needed, or generic window rod OK?

Tags: windows, sliding-glass-door

I have a sliding glass door in my master bedroom, which leads out to my backyard. I need to get a replacement drape rod and mounts. Will any window curtain rod kit be suitable, or are there special kits designed for sliding doors?

I ask because I believe generic window rods are mounted into the drywall. Since a sliding door might get more traffic, I'm not sure if this would be strong enough as the drapes will be tugged on more. Also I'm not sure if the clearance that generic window rod kits provide is suitable for a sliding door setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and did not really have much room above the door frame to mount anything aesthetically please to the eye.  What I landed on was [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CUD6RT2).

My sliding glass door is off my kitchen and into the backyard, so in the spring and summer months it gets more traffic.  The panels easily slide back and forth with ease and putting

Answer (score 1):

Any large curtain rod should be mounted to framing. There's no special rod for patio doors, but it is up to you to use common sense in mounting.

If you're unable to hit framing, use togglers of one type or another to grab the drywall from the back side and spread the load. Do not use drive-in plugs or screw-in anchors. They're sure to wiggle loose over time with any curtain, regardless of location.

Answer (score 1):

I always try to hit a stud with curtains but if I cannot I use spin in anchors they are easy to remove and fill the hole compared to Molly bolts that if a change is needed in the future Molly's have to be punched through the sheet rock or possibly unscrewed and push the screw then pull on the flange to remove but this tends to leave a larger hole to patch. I have never had a problem with EZ spin in anchors backing out and because of the diameter they hold and are ez to remove.